# Dynamic post/put routing in ExpressJS

Tags: node.js, angularjs, express

I'm using Angular on the client side, Express on the server. I've got two forms on the same page. I need both forms to post to the same URL, but use a different controller method, depending on a variable that I can grab from the request body.

Obviously the routes listed below would work individually, but since I need both, having two PUTs on the same URL won't work:

```
app.put('/articles/:articleId', articles.update);

app.put('/articles/:articleId', articles.addEditor);
```

In pseudo-express code, what I'd like is:

```
app.put('/article/:articleId', function(req) {
     if (req.editor) {
          articles.addEditor;
     } else {
          articles.update;
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
app.put('/article/:articleId', function(req, res, next) {
    if (req.body.editor) {
        articles.addEditor(req, res, next);
    } else {
        articles.update(req, res, next);
    }
});
```

Comment: Seems so, no reason the above shouldn't work, as long as you pass the `req` and `res` objects on to the next function you should be fine.,